# How to control the @PostConstruct when integration testing using Spring

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, integration-testing

I have spring bean class RedisRepo
inside I am initialising my database connection with @PostConstruct:

```
 @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        logger.debug("RedisRepo, Init.");
        client = new RedisClient(REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT);
        ...
    }
```

I am creating this bean using java config at SpringConfiguration.class:

```
 @Bean
    @Scope("singleton")
    public RedisRepo redisjRepo() {
        return new RedisRepo();
    }
```

I started to build Integration tests using Spring.
I am using the same configuration class (SpringConfiguration.class) for tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SpringConfiguration.class)
```

My Test class using embedded-redis so I need to init it right before I start my tests:

```
 @Before
    public void init() throws IOException {
//init embedded-redis
}
```

The problem is when I start the tests the @PostConstruct of the RedisRepo class executed before my integration-test init() class (past below) which leading me to null since my embedded redis hasnt initialised just yet.

How could I avoid it?
Mybe I am not doing something right?

Thanks,
ray.

Comment: Could you add a second test configuration in which you initialize your embeded redis? Or annotate the `init` method with `@BeforeClass` instead of `@Before`?

Comment: @BeforeClass did the work. is that how I should do it? what you meant by creating second config? ill need to change for that my RedisRepo file aswell

Comment: You can pass more than one configuration class to `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` so you could define a configuration to use on top of `SpringConfiguration` for integration tests. However this might not work due to dependencies and declared beans in `SpringConfiguration`. However take a look at the Spring testing chapter, if you haven't already: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

Comment: @hotzst i read that one. it won't help me to use diff configuration file since ill need to creare RedisRepo bean anyway which eventually invoke it's postconstruct before i manage to execute my embedded-redis server

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to consider using spring Boot auto-configuration (`@EnableAutoConfiguration` or `@SpringBootApplication`) to initialize Redis connection. You can use these [Spring Boot properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) to customize Redis:

```
# REDIS (RedisProperties)
spring.redis.database= # database name
spring.redis.host=localhost # server host
spring.redis.password= # server password
spring.redis.port=6379 # connection port
spring.redis.pool.max-idle=8 # pool settings ...
spring.redis.pool.min-idle=0
spring.redis.pool.max-active=8
spring.redis.pool.max-wait=-1
spring.redis.sentinel.master= # name of Redis server
spring.redis.sentinel.nodes= # comma-separated list of host:port pairs
```

This would remove need for connection initialization in `@PostConstruct` production code and you can just autowire your Redis related beans from context dusting testing.

**EDIT1:**

To populate Redis instance before testing method you can use `@BeforeMethod` (using TestNg) or `@Before` (using JUnit). To populate it before the test but after the context is initialized use @PostConstruct in test class.

**EDIT2:**

You asked on generic rule how to overcome need for initialization of resources in `@PostConstruct`. I believe your problem is how you are wiring beans in your application.

Your `@PostConstruct` initialization is done in other bean, where `RedisClient` is stored as variable `client`. I would argue that it most probably mixing of concerns. If you register `RedisClient` bean into spring context this way:

```
@Bean
public RedisClient redisClient() {
    RedisClient client = new RedisClient(REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT);
    ...
    return client;
}
```

You can just autowire it into bean where you had `@PostConstruct` initialization. You are also able to autowire it during test. If `RedisClient` is not thread-safe, you may want to consider prototype or request scope for it.

With this approach, I extremely rarely use `@PostConstruct` and use Spring IoC container to handle all the reusable resource instances.

Comment: i need to init my code which starting embedded redis server before I init any connections to Redis.. hows that solve my issue?

Comment: Well now you mybe solved my prob with Redis. but I also have other 3rd party services like neo4j.. how would you overcome that? look at the redis-case just as specific one.. Could you have some generic idea ?